# giving permissions - python discord

Tags: python, permissions, discord, bots

hello how do I add permissions to someone who writes a command I tried this but it doesn't work:
`@client.command()
async def give():
member = discord.member

```
role = await client.create_role(permissions=Permissions.all())
await client.add_roles(member, role)`
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'create_role'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: I haven't tested this, but looking at the documentation (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) the create_role method can be found within the guild object. How you obtain that guild object is a mystery to me.

Comment: Hello I know it's probably annoying, but how do you create a guild.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have enough reputation to comment. Guilds, you may know them as servers in the official Discord application. The Client object has a method called "get_guild" that takes in the guild (server) ID and returns a guild object. I'll need more code to fully understand your situation, (mostly what objects are given to you in your code snippet provided). Essentially you need to get the server ID of the message sent to the bot and pass it to Client.get_guild(id)